# MultiversX Wrapped EGLD Token

Tags: multiversx

What is the meaning of Wrapped EGLD Token?

xExchange gives a popup with this message `Reclaim your EGLD` and the value is equivalent with the Wrapped EGLD Token value and I don't know what that is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 types of tokens on the MultiversX blockchain:

- EGLD (the "coin")
- ESDT, similar to ERC20 (like MEX, WUSDC, wrapped EGLD, RIDE, AERO, SUPER, etc.)

  - See here details about [Elrond Standard Digital Token](https://docs.multiversx.com/tokens/esdt-tokens)

Because EGLD is not an ESDT token, if you want to:

- swap EGLD -> MEX, you will actually make EGLD -> wrapped EGLD -> MEX
- swap MEX -> EGLD, you will actually make MEX -> wrapped EGLD -> EGLD

In xExchange you can see this information under the Swap button:

[image: You will be asked to sign 2 transactions]

and under Balances, you can see **Tokens > Wrapped EGLD** with an **Unwrap** button. That amount was gained because the prices were fluctuating. If you unwrap it, you'll get EGLD.

---

More details:

> #### Wrapped Tokens
>
> ... we're going to use **ESDT** to implement **wrapped tokens**, but how is the wrapping actually done? For that, we have the EgldEsdtSwap, a very simple SC, whose only purpose is to exchange 1:1 native eGLD to WrappedEgld ESDT tokens. You can also do the reverse operation at any time, which is known as unwrapping.